# doc.sent to text file

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I have written a custom boundary detection:

```
def new_custom_bondary(docx):
    for token in docx[:-1]:
        if token.text == ".":
            docx[token.i+1].is_sent_start=True
    return docx
```

Then I have added to the spacy nlp pipeline:

```
nlp.add_pipe(new_custom_boundary,before = 'parser')
```

### Problem

I would like to store the result in text file, but when I'm trying to loop through `doc.sents`, and write to text file, it's actually writing only the last line of the output. Whether the problem is due to the looping, or something related to span/doc in spacy, I don't know.

Could anyone me help out with this?

[image: code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of code are not searchable, nor are they accessible. Please [edit] the question and replace the images of code with the actual code, and then properly format it using the tools like the "{}" button in the question editor.

Comment: I actually did that but everytime it gave me error while formatting it.. so thats why i thought to post the code image and thank you for suggestion and advice, will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rewriting output.txt for every row.

When you do

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write(str(sent))
```

the 'w' parameters tell to write over the file.

You have to change the open mode to 'a', which stands for "append":

```
#this will append lines instead of rewriting.
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
       f.write(str(sent)+"\n")
```

Comment: actually here i am doing a sentence segmentation. so , if i do ''append'',  it just copy the complete content as it is from ''filename.txt'' to ''output.txt'' without sentence segmentated for which i wrote a custom boundary detection.. as mentioned above..

Comment: You want one file per sentence?

Comment: I actually want all the contents of filename.txt , which is not sentences segemented (as it is complete text ) to output.txt with one sentences per line.

Comment: Just add \n to the end of each string

Comment: i hope you have seen my custom boundary code above and according to that I break the sentence which end with dot. So the code executing successfully on jupyter notebook when i print the result but same code when i tell it to write to file its only writting the last line of the output

Comment: finally got the result as i wanted. Thank you @Tiago Duque

Comment: Printing by default creates a new line in Python. It does not happen in file writing, though. Don't forget to accept the answer.